# Positive invertible elements and pure states in unital C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In a unital C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, if $a\in\mathcal{A}$ is a positive element such that $\|a\|=1$, and, for every pure state $f$, $f(a)>0$. Show $a$ is invertible.

Can I conclude, for every state $g\in S(\mathcal{A})$, we always have $g(a)>0$? Since that's true for every pure state?

I'm trying to use that potentially problematic claim to prove invertibility of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the $C^*$-algebra generated by $a,1$. Then I claim that if $g$ is a pure state on $\mathcal{B}$, then also $g(a)> 0$.

To see this, choose a pure state $\overline{g}$ on $\mathcal{A}$ that restricts to $g$ on $\mathcal{B}$. Then $g(a) = \overline{g}(a)> 0$ by your assumption.

Thus, your condition is also satisfied for the commutative $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$. Thus, we may assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative (by replacing it by $\mathcal{B}$).

But from there, the proof is easy: By the commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem, we have $\mathcal{A}\cong C(X)$ where $X$ is some compact Hausdorff space. Then recall that the pure states on $C(X)$ are precisely the characters $\{\operatorname{ev}_x: x \in X\}$ so your assumption means that
$$a(x) = \operatorname{ev}_x(a)>0$$
for any $x\in X$. Hence, $a$ is invertible.

Comment: For completeness, you may want to mention that each pure state on $C^*(a)$ extends to a pure state on $A$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace What do you mean by "replacing $\mathcal{A}$"? Do you mean the statement is true only when $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative? Or do you mean it works for all $\mathcal{A}$? Can we claim "for every pure state $g$ on $\mathcal{A}$ such that $g(a)=0$, there is a character $f_g$ on $C^*(a)$ such that $f_g(a)=0$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace: yes, you replied right as I changed my comment.

Comment: @user760 Added more details. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: @QuantumSpace But is every pure state of $\mathcal{B}$ the restriction of a pure state on $\mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{B}:= C^*\left(1_\mathcal{A}, a\right)$ ?

Comment: @user760 Yes, this is a fact about pure states you can find in elementary C*-algebra books.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Another question that might be silly: are we guaranteed $a$ is invertible in $\mathcal{A}$ if and only if it is in $\mathcal{B}$? As I know, the definition of $\mathcal{B}$ is the "smallest C*-subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $1$ and $a$ are included. Does that guarantee $a^{-1}$ lies in $\mathcal{B}$ if it exists?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Just a thought. Can we use the fact that the direct sum of GNS representations corresponding to pure states is faithful? Can we claim if all pure states are non-zero at $a$, then the operator corresponding to $a$ is invertible? Then deduce $a$ is invertible by faithfulness?

Comment: Yes, I was writing that answer when QuantumSpace wrote his better one. As for your other question, in C$^*$-algebras the spectrum does not change when you pass to a subalgebra.

Comment: @user760 It is a remarkable fact about $C^*$-algebras, that $a$ is invertible in $\mathcal{B}$ if and only if it is invertible in $\mathcal{A}$. However, you don't need the full strength of this answer: if $a$ is invertible in $\mathcal{B}$, then surely it is invertible in $\mathcal{A}$ (it is the converse that is non-trivial, but you don't need it here).

Comment: @MartinArgerami Sorry to drag this on, but can you provide the steps to conclude the corresponding operator isinvertible, in the faithful representation answer? I was trying to prove it but got stuck. From $f(a)>0$ for all pure states $f$ to π(a) being invertible in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, that is. Maybe post another answer, if you have time? It might be basic to experts, but I'm a new learner. Many thanks.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thanks! That certainly makes sense. Sorry if I aksed too many obvious quesitons. I'm a new learner.

Comment: @user760 No problem, we have all been at that point :)

Comment: @user760: on second thought, I don't think I can make it work. When I think of how to prove that if $f(a)>0$ for **all** states then $a$ is invertible, the compactness of the state space plays a crucial role. This suggests confining the problem to the abelian case (where the pure state space **is** compact) and that leads precisely to QuantumSpace's argument.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Another question is: if $0$ is a cluster point of $\{f(a)\}$ for all pure states $f$, does that impact the invertibility of $a$ in $\mathcal{B}$, in the Gelfand representation? Since, before we have proved the claim, we can't rule that out. Right?